# Only allowing purchases in the US with Stripe

Tags: api, stripe-payments

Novice programmer here, [using this setup for stripe](https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Node.js-Stripe-Shopping-Cart) (mostly vanilla js and node).

I wanted to make it so only people in the US and Canada can buy a t-shirt from me. I see on [Stripe's docs that this API is depreciated](https://stripe.com/docs/orders).

Any suggestions as to how I would do this?

Comment: You likely need to use [Stripe Radar Rules w/ Conditions](https://stripe.com/docs/radar/rules/reference#conditions). You should contact [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) if you have additional questions about how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to use [Radar](https://stripe.com/radar) which lets you build [custom rules](https://stripe.com/docs/radar/rules) to control which payments you want to accept and which ones you want to block. This would let you create a rule blocking any payment coming from a card that wasn't issued in Canada or the United States. This is documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/radar/rules#block-rules) and the rule would look like this:

```
NOT (:card_country: IN ('FR','IE','ES'))
```

Otherwise, if you want to do this programmatically, the best option is to look at the `country` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card-country) of a card PaymentMethod and reject payments if the country is not `US` or `CA`.